# Load swagger UI contents in https - Lumen

Tags: laravel, apache, https, swagger, lumen

I have hosted my Lumen(version : 5.7.8), in my apache server. The site has been accessed using https. So in App\Providers\AppServiceProvider I have added

```
public function boot()
{
    \URL::forceScheme('https');
}
```

When I run swagger,which I have installed using DarkaOnline, it is showing blank page and got the following error in the console.

> Uncaught ReferenceError: SwaggerUIBundle is not defined

And all swagger ui css and js files still shows its path loading from http, which ends up in following error in console.

> Blocked loading mixed active content

Should I need to enable or do something more to load everything in https ?
I am using swagger  1.0.0 , OAS3

Comment: Try updating the variables `L5_SWAGGER_CONST_HOST` and `APP_URL` in your `.env` file, refresh your config cache and check.

Comment: I have APP_URL in my .env, but what is L5_SWAGGER_CONST_HOST ?

Comment: Check the `config/l5-swagger.php` file. It is the API Host URL used by swagger.